# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I already searched for this error but the provided solution does not work. Visual studio nuget packages does not show installed mvc package to upgrade.

During deployment, getting the above mentioned error.
Please let me know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Every time I've had this issue, it's always been an issue with the web config file. Check that your reference in your ~/Views/web.config is the correct one, and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the same published version code is deployed on other server. When i try to redeploy on a new server, I am getting the above mentioned error. I am doing server migration, so same published version should also work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this package: Download Web Pages 2 from Official Microsoft Download Center: [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34600)